# Why doesn't BeautifulSoup scrape the entirety of the webpage and ow to get it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some data, from this [webpage](https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/money-line/1st-half/?date=20160601). All the text is visible on the page, however, when I grab it with BSoup I cant find any of the numbers for odds.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/money-line/1st-half/?date=20160601"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
driver.quit()

opener = soup.findAll('span' , {'class' : 'opener'})

print opener
```

What's even weirder, it worked once, then stopped for no apparent reason or changes to the code. When I checked what soup scrapes from this page, the numbers for odds weren't even included.

Why don't I get all the data and what to do to get it?

Comment: The site most likely uses js to generate parts of the site, so BS will not work.

Comment: *All the text is visible on the page.* Really? Turn off `JavaScript` and *see* what's really visible. What you'll see is what you get when you request the page source `HTML`.

Comment: OK I had no idea about JavaScript. This should point me in the right direction. Time to start learning. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `Selenium` to make `javascript` triggered then extract data you want in this case code below can help :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# also look at options
driver = webdriver.Chrome('address_of_your_driver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("your_URL_here")

# now you've got the source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what does 'address_of_your_driver' stand for here? English is not my native language and this is boggling my mind. Tnx for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: your local path to the exe file

Comment: @chitown88 download it from here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @iliya. yes download from there.

Comment: How to get the data I want from page_source?

Comment: @user1851527 the data is in this variable soup. Print this variable you get the whole source